# Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint dev tools - can "Feature1.feature" be renamed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

If I create an empty SharePoint 2010 project in VS2010, then add features to the project, the features are named Feature1.feature and Feature2.feature, etc, etc. I'd like to give these features a sensible name in VS2010, for example MyCustomFeature.feature and MyOtherCustomFeature.feature, but I can't work out how to do this. VS2010 provides "right-click, rename" support, but it does not work for me.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer to my question. The environment I am working in has a tilde character at the start of all Active Directory login names, for example '~abc'. The default file save location in Visual Studio is therefore 'C:\Users\~abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects'.

The Sharepoint tools in VS2010 do not like that tilde character. The tilde prevents you from renaming any of the "FeatureX" nodes under the Features folder. VS2010 or the event log do not report an error, the rename just fails. As soon as you move the project to C:\MyTestProject, feature rename works just fine.

Additionally, a user cannot create a My Site if the login name contains the tilde character:

> Event ID 5187: My Site creation failure for user 'DOMAIN\~abc' for
>   site url 'http://[webapp]/personal/~abc'. The exception was:
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.PersonalSiteCreateException: A
>   failure was encountered while attempting to create the site. --->
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: "/personal/~abc" contains illegal
>   character '~'.

KB905231 warns against having a tilde in Active Directory group names, but not login names:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;905231.

My advice - avoid the tilde!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the list: My project had a comma in the path, VS wasn't allowing me to rename the feature. I took off the comma and was able to rename the feature. It seems SharePoint Tools doesn't like anything "unusual" on the project path. Thanks to PeteL and Yuri that pointed me to the solution.

Comment: Same thing happened to me with the '&' character

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS  2010 and SharePoint tools, looking to this theme I decide to create a new project without any illegal chars in path, after several experiments I found out that my actual path contained '!' symbol, in root folder name - 'd:!Projects' that doesn't allow to change the feature name. Also both '_' and '.' work fine in folder names.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Do you have Source Control? I had some issues where I was using SVN and I couldn't rename a file I've just created because SVN was telling me I had uncommited changes. After commiting, renaming worked fine.

It's definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I too am sure it's possible, I've seen screenshots where people have done it. I'll check my installation. It's driving me crazy, but your message does help! Thanks again.

Comment: By the way, yes, SVN is on that machine. I think you may have hit the nail on the head there. I'll check at work tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @PeteL Also check the output window (View > Output). I was using AnknSVN as a Visual Studio SVN plugin and it gave a clear message there. (We've switched to TFS since, so I can't check right now)

Answer (score 0):

I use SharePoint 2010 projects  in VS2010 with TFS and have some sort of hack to rename newly added feature with default name "Feature" to the project.
1) Exclude feature from the project - it will disappear in the project tree but will still visible if you click **"Show All Files"**
2) Rename file "Feature1.feature" and its parent folder via the properties window or right click on the feature file and select "Rename" option. Make sure that file "Feature1.feature" and its parent folder have the same names e.g. "ListsAndContentTypes.feature" for feature file 
and "ListsAndContentTypes" for the parent folder
3) Right click on the parent feature folder  (in example above "ListsAndContentTypes" ) and click "Include in project"
Now the feature file have appropriate name.
4) Make sure that it is included in the package - check the   "Package" project item.

Hope this helps.